# Prisma One-to-One relations are not uniquely accessible from both sides

Tags: typescript, prisma

I have the following models (simplified)

```
model User {
  id           String  @id @default(cuid())
  primarySetId String? @unique
  PrimarySet   Set?    @relation("primary", fields: [primarySetId], references: [id])
}

model Set {
  id          String @id @default(cuid())
  PrimaryUser User?  @relation("primary")
}
```

It's just a One-to-One relation between User and Set, with the foreign key residing in User

The problem is the Prisma client can't use the User model's id, to uniquely search for a Set.

```
await prisma.set.findUnique({
  'where': {
    'PrimaryUser': {
        'id': 'user_id'
      },
    }
  })
```

I get typescript errors telling me that I need to provide the set.id, defeating the purpose of searching for the set. I expected a one-to-one relation to be counted as unique, and be usable in this scenario.

The only way to search for this set is to findFirst or include it in the User search, but this does not help when upserting a set. I feel like I'm missing something, because otherwise it seems upserting is impossible without a second query?